# Hiding symbols from gnustl_static when build with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am building an Android library that contains a native part written using STL that is hidden under Java wrapper. In NDK documentation in a section [Static runtimes](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html) it is stated that I should use shared runtime to avoid problems with multiple static runtimes, but I want to try using `gnustl_static` with a flag `-fvisibility=hidden` set. 
The question is, will it solve possible problems or a shared library is the only way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, building with `-fvisibility=hidden` will not help with the problems created by linking multiple libraries to a static C++ runtime.

Unless you are building `gnustl_static` yourself, the `-fvisibility=hidden` flag only applies to your native code which depends on `gnustl_static`. It won't change how the symbols are exported from `gnustl_static`.

> In addition, if you link two shared libraries–or a shared library and
>   an executable– against the same static runtime, the final binary image
>   of each shared library includes a copy of the runtime's code. Having
>   multiple instances of runtime code is problematic because of
>   duplication of certain global variables that the runtime uses or
>   provides internally.

However, linking against a static C++ runtime should work perfectly fine as long as you are only creating one shared library.

> This problem does not apply to a project comprising a single shared
>   library. For example, you can link against stlport_static, and expect
>   your app to behave correctly. If your project requires several shared
>   library modules, we recommend that you use the shared library variant
>   of your C++ runtime.

Comment: Thank you, I want to clarify, that my library will not be linked as a native library with client code, it will be added as a Java library. It has a native 'guts' that are loaded as a shared library in a static block, so the users should not even know that I am gonna use native code.

Comment: If you only have the one shared library containing the 'guts', you shouldn't have any problems with either a static or shared runtime :)